# blender python Rendering - log explanation

Tags: python, render, blender

When executing my program, some information not possible to be interpreted by myself is printed in the cmd window. The following picture shows the concerning lines: 
[image: printed output]

I am working with blender and execute my .py file together with my .blend file like this (-b for background mode):

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender"
blender -b ...\simulator.blend --python ...\main.py
```

The shown lines occure when rendering, executed by this code:

```
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
```

Most important to me is, what means: Part x-y ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the same progress information that you would see in the image editor if you were watching the rendering within blender's GUI. As you are rendering from the CLI, each progress update prints out on a new line.

When you render, the image is broken into tiles with each being rendered separately on a different CPU, the tile settings can be found in the `Performance` panel within the render settings. The "Part x-y" (or "Path Tracing Tile x/y" when you are using cycles) is specifying which tile the progress is reporting on, with the second number being the total number of tiles to render.